# Executing a Number of Classes Java

Tags: java, compilation, execute

Currently I have a folder with 6 classes. The main class being called "Interaction".

I compile all the classes by using javac *.java

How do I run the program? When I type "java Interaction" I get errors as the other classes are not being loaded. Its as if I need to link the other 4 classes into the main class. How do I do this?

Im using windows command prompt

Thanks
Philip

Do I need to set all the program in a package or something?

Comment: Can you verify that all the class files are in the same directory? What about the package name? IIRC they need to align with your directory structure.

Comment: The error message given by running `java` would be useful in getting an idea about what may be going on.

Comment: Can you include the error message?

Comment: Exception in Thread main NullPointerException
at Amalgamateds.init(26)
at Interaction.main(98)

but when i run it from eclipse, i get no errors. So there is nothing wrong with the code. Its not loading the amalgamated class

Comment: Its the default package, all in the same folder

Comment: The Problem is the object which is dereferenced in line 26 of Amalgamateds.init(). Is there a resource you pass from Interaction which is not found outside eclipse, lookup in eclipse project-settings which will be used also for excecution

Comment: So basically, when you said "I get errors as the other classes are not being loaded", you were talking out your ass.  NullPointerException is not the same thing as "ClassNotFoundException".

Comment: When will people learn to provide a full stacktrace when reporting problems? This is so sick...

Answer (score 0):

Look at the CLASSPATH variable by typing "echo %CLASSPATH%" on the command prompt.
Make sure it includes the current directory and any required jars.
Compare it with the one used by Eclipse.